# Using the create method to make a new instance of API data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, model-view-controller

I am pulling game data from an API (https://github.com/games-directory/api-giantbomb) where users can search through games and add it to their library. However I can't get the Create method working that is supposed to create an instance of the game called from the API and post it to the user's library page.

I have my associations set up across four models: Game, User, Library, and Library_Game:

Game.rb

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :library_games
  has_many :libraries, through: :library_games
  has_many :users, through: :libraries
  serialize :data

  def fetch_data
    game = GiantBomb::Game.detail(id)
    self.data = Hash[game.instance_variables.map { |var| [var.to_s[1..-1], game.instance_variable_get(var)] } ]
  end

  def to_giant_bomb_game
    GiantBomb::Game.new(data)
  end
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :libraries
  has_many :games, through: :libraries

  def has_game?(game)
    games.where(id: game.id).exist?
  end
end
```

Library.rb

```
class Library < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :library_games
  has_many :games, through: :library_games
end
```

Library_Game.rb

```
class LibraryGame < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :library
  belongs_to :game
  has_one :user, through: :library
end
```

I am routing the create method through the Games Controller. Here is my create method along with the strong params.

```
def create
    @library_game = Game.new(game_params)
    @library_game.fetch_data
    @library_game.save
    redirect_to library_path
  end

private

  def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:data)
  end

end
```

I get an error on my fetch_data method saying "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass". However if I take out the @library_games.fetch_data part of my create method, it redirects to my library but there is no instance of the game.

My link_to in my view that is supposed to attach the game to a user's library:

```
<%= link_to 'Add to library', create_path(current_user, game: game), method: :post %>
```

And the library controller's index that is supposed to display the games.

```
class LibraryController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @library_games = User.find(params[:id]).games
  end
end
```

The view for the library index:

```
<% if @library_games.exists? %>
<% @library_games.map(&:to_giant_bomb_game).each do |game| %>
#etc.
```

What should I be doing in my create method to create a new instance of the API data that can save to a user's library?

Comment: Note that `has_game?` can be more simply written as `games.include?(game)`. And should, of course, be `got_game?`. :)

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: Error is coming up on game = GiantBomb::Game.detail(id) for my fetch_data method in my game profile. It says 'undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass'. I'm a bit confused about how to assign the API data to a new instance of Game.

Comment: There's no `each` on that line. Is it happening inside the `GiantBomb::Game` class? Could you show the stack trace?

Comment: `GiantBomb::Game.detail(id)` is using the database ID for `Game`. Does that ID have any meaning to the API?

Comment: Note that `@library_game.save` might be failing and you wouldn't know. Use [`save!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save-21) so you get an exception if the save fails. Similarly, `find!`, `create!`, and `update!`.

Comment: It's happening inside my Game.rb's fetch_data function. I thought that seralizing the data would allow me to use GiantBomb::Game.detail(id) for the game's ID. I tried save! but I still get the same error.